# flexbox: align center if image is taller, flex-start if text is taller

Tags: css, flexbox

Imagine a site component with text on the left and an image on the right, which scales with the page width. The image does not scale, but the text width is fluid. The text content can change. I'm using flexbox to achieve this.

Example:

```html
<main>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/any">
  </div>
</main>
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
/*   align-items: flex-start; */
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 2em;
}

h1, p {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 + p {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

View this example at https://codepen.io/marcvangend/pen/xModrN.

On smaller screen widths, when the text is taller, I want the text and image to align at the top. `align-items: flex-start;` would do this. On wider screens, when the image height is taller than the text, I want both elements be centered vertically, as `align-items: center;` does.

Is there a clean way (no JS) to automatically switch between the two alignments, depending on which element is taller?

Answer (score 3):

While writing this question, the solution occurred to me :-)

It is pretty simple fortunately, just add:

```css
.image {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```